# Handle leak on socket create/destroy in Metro

Tags: sockets, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, memory-leaks, c++-cx

I'm trying to write network application under Windows 8 Metro.
My application needs to create/destroy some amount of sockets at runtime. While trying to study out WinRT's Network API, I've found following issue - my process continuously increase it's Handle count while it create/destroy sockets.
To confirm that I've wrote following sample:

```
task<void>( []()
{
  // <checkpoint 1>

  for(int i=0; i < 200; i++)
  {
    // create socket
    DatagramSocket    ^socket = ref new DatagramSocket();

    // perform binding operation synchronously
    HRESULT  hr = S_OK;
    HostName ^localHostName     = ref new HostName(L"127.0.0.1");
    String   ^localServiceName  = L"10000";

    create_task( socket->BindEndpointAsync(localHostName, localServiceName) ).then(
      [&hr] (task<void> previousTask)
      {
        try
        {
          previousTask.get();  // get exception
        }
        catch (Exception^ exception)
        {
          hr = exception->HResult;
        }
      }).wait();

    ASSERT( SUCCEEDED(hr) );

    // close socket
    delete socket;      // C++ version of DatagramSocket.Close(), see MSDN
    socket = nullptr;
  }

  // <checkpoint 2>
});
```

This task is created in main App's thread.
I've set 2 breakpoints at  and  and run Sysinternal's Handle utility there:

At checkpoint 1 (before starting create/destroy loop):

```
Handle type summary:
  ALPC Port       : 10
  Desktop         : 1
  Directory       : 4
  EtwRegistration : 34
  Event           : 40
  File            : 3
  IoCompletion    : 2
  Key             : 17
  Mutant          : 1
  Section         : 5
  Semaphore       : 4
  Thread          : 9
  Timer           : 7
  TpWorkerFactory : 2
  WaitCompletionPacket: 7
  WindowStation   : 2
Total handles: 148
```

At checkpoint 2 (after the loop):

```
Handle type summary:
  ALPC Port       : 9
  Desktop         : 1
  Directory       : 4
  EtwRegistration : 40
  Event           : 80
  File            : 5
  IoCompletion    : 145
  Key             : 20
  Mutant          : 1
  Section         : 5
  Semaphore       : 6
  Thread          : 26
  Timer           : 291
  TpWorkerFactory : 144
  WaitCompletionPacket: 295
  WindowStation   : 2
Total handles: 1074
```

According to this, my app continuously leaks Timer, WaitCompletionPacket and other handles.
(I've tried to wait some time after the loop or insert delay into the loop hoping that workers will do their work, but none help).
So what's wrong with this sample and how should I create/bind/destroy socket objects?
I'm using Windows 8 Consumer Preview, build 8400.

Comment: Did you try printing `hr`'s value ? Binding many sockets to the same port is likely to fail from the second time ... By being stretching things a bit I could say that your `ASSERT` crashes the top task silently and that deleted is not called ... (though there are many possibilities for this idea to be wrong, just in case).

Comment: Sure. hr is S_OK all the time. Assert will fire if I comment "delete socket;". In this case socket close operation seems to be delayed (by worker thread) and may interfere with next loop iteration.

Comment: Your code looks fine.

It's possible this was a leak either in C++/CX or in the PPL extensions in the Consumer Preview build.  Either way, with the RTM version of VS and RTM Windows 8, I am unable to reproduce this leak, so you should find that this leak is fixed when you update to RTM.

Comment: Thank you! Just tested it in new fresh Windows 8 RTM environment and confirmed what you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andy mentioned, the issue has gone after updating Windows 8 Consumer Preview to Windows 8 RTM (as well as Visual Studio).